# Float layout // how to position properly third div under first

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

*There are so many questions about floating to find my exact problem, sorry if i posted a copy...*

---

I want div #3 to be directly under div #1 if browser width is not enough to support it going right of div #2.
Floating it all to left is what I found best option.

Problem is, even when float to left, div #3 is going under div #2 height.
Is there easy way to fix this, to appear as if div #2 is floated right instead. (I can't do this, since i don't want fixed width of container element).

Goal: I want left one to look exactly like right one, just without using: float: right; since i don't want fixed page width. I hope it makes it more clear.

I am aware of @media property in CSS, but i would like to learn easier solution for this if possible.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VWhx8/)

---

***Edit:***

Managed to hack it with: http://jsfiddle.net/WEL6p/

*one is absolute position to #1 which is relative. Then add fixer which float to left and visibility: none; with same width as #2 and some small height.*

---

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="top">1</div>
    <div id="right">2</div>
    <div id="bottom">3</div>

</div>

<div id="container2">

    <div id="top2">1</div>
    <div id="right2">2</div>
    <div id="bottom2">3</div>

</div>
```

---

CSS:

```
div {display: inline-block; font-size: 50px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; color: white;}
div div {background: red; margin: 10px; border: 2px solid black;}
/* ------------------- LEFT ------------------------ */
#container {width: 350px; border: 2px solid green; float: left;}

#top {width: 200px; height: 100px; float: left;}
#bottom {width: 200px; height: 100px; float: left;}
#right {width: 100px; height: 300px; float: left;}
/* ------------------- RIGHT ----------------------- */
#container2 {width: 350px; border: 2px solid green; margin-left: 10px;}

#top2 {width: 200px; height: 100px; float: left;}
#bottom2 {width: 200px; height: 100px; float: left;}
#right2 {width: 100px; height: 300px; float: right;}
```

Comment: Is div #1 and div #3 always going to be the same width regardless of browser width?

Comment: It looks like you have done exactly what you want in your second container??

Comment: Yes, they are all in pixels width as in example, just no container element.

Comment: Yes Danield, but i don't want container element in my page: i want div #3 to be on right side for div#2 if screen is large enough.

2nd container is just to show what i want it too look like.

Comment: I think this can't be solved with just CSS layouts (I'm not sure about the newest Flex layout, but this layout is currently not supported by many browsers). You can try finding some solution using script. I made this fiddle using some kind of hack, I'm sure it is not exactly what you want, but it's usable in some limited condition, such as the `div2` contains only text or image http://jsfiddle.net/VWhx8/5/

Comment: Actually, I will be using table with like 500 rows in that div #2, so this wont really help.

Comment: If all divs are given width in % relative to parent then the layout won't break when window is resized. for it to break any of the divs should have a fixed width that is not changing with resize. in your case which div has a fixed width?

Comment: all 3 have fixed width.

Comment: I managed to hack it with another div like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/WEL6p/

#2 one is absolute position to #1 which is relative.
Then add fixer which float to left and visibility: none; with same width as #2 and some small height.

Comment: @Nightwhistle great, that's very like the idea I used, however you have a real element inserted in the HTML code while I use a pseudo-element `:before`, the real element can contain anything (not only text and image). Looks like your problem has been solved, you should post your own answer and accept it so that others can benefit if they have the same problem. (should not post the answer in the edit).

Comment: Not really, when i shrink it even more, the fixer element gets in between #1 and #3 and make a gap ^^

Your fix is cool, just, I guess i don't understand :before :after good enough, since I'm not sure how to show entire table in div #2 using content:''; in after pseudo thingy.

Comment: I guess i found the working hack, cant answer my question yet as for new account have to wait 8 hours :)

Credits to @KingKing for idea.

div #1 is relative, floating to left.
div #2 is absolute and positioned to right with left: property.
div # is floating to left.

Then just add margin-right to div#1 with div#2 width + margins in between.

http://jsfiddle.net/WEL6p/1/

Comment: @Nightwhistle this was my idea, which is why i asked for the width of a fixed div. You can do this only  if div2 has fixed width.. i forgot to get back to this Q in the mean time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess i found the working hack:

div #1 is relative, floating to left.
div #2 is absolute and positioned to right with {left: } property.
div #3 is floating to left.

Then just add {margin-right: } to div#1 with div#2 width + margins in between.

http://jsfiddle.net/WEL6p/1/

*credits to people that hinted me to right direction  :)

ty very much*

---

HTML:

```
<div id="top">1</div>
<div id="right">2</div>
<div id="bottom">3</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {display: inline-block; font-size: 50px; text-align: center; color: white; border: 2px solid black;}
div {background: red; margin: 10px;}


#top {width: 200px; height: 100px; float: left; position: relative; margin-right: 130px;}
#bottom {width: 200px; height: 100px; float: left;}
#right {width: 100px; height: 300px; position: absolute; left: 230px;}
```